# SaltStack lazy variable evaluation when rendering template

Tags: salt-stack

I need to get the default gateway ip address of docker0 network interface in my SaltStack state file. The .sls might look like this

```
include:
    - docker

postgresql:
    docker.running:
        - container: postgresql 
        - port_bindings:
            "5432/tcp":
                HostIp: {{ grains['ip_interfaces']['docker0'][0]}}
                HostPort: "5432"
```

This works when docker was provisioned before I run `state.highstate`, however, when this template is rendered by SaltStack, the docker is not actually provisioned, so `docker0` network interface is not available by the time. As a result, a key error will be raised.

I know in most cases, the docker0 default gateway will be `172.17.42.1` and I can set it to this value directly. However, what if I encounter another situation like this? Is there any way to render the template lazily, I think that would be something like

```
lazy_render: True
```

So that it will be rendered only before executing it. Is there anything like this available in SaltStack? Or do you guys have other solution for this issue?

Comment: seems salt renders the jinja as the first step, then runs the states. Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should either wait for docker state execution or some other conditional.

e.g.

```
include:
    - docker

postgresql:
    docker.running:
        - container: postgresql 
        - port_bindings:
            "5432/tcp":
                HostIp: {{ grains['ip_interfaces']['docker0'][0]}}
                HostPort: "5432"
        - require:
          - sls: docker
```

Comment: That doesn't help, the problem comes from the jinja rendering that is done before executing any states. I have the same kind of problem... looking for a solution.